# Синонимизировать [закон] и [юридические-аспекты]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метки:

- [закон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd) (23 вопроса, есть описание).
- [юридические-аспекты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8e%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b) (25 вопросов, есть описание).

Мне кажется, что они являются синонимами. Ведь в описании метки [закон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd) сказано:

> Эта метка используется для вопросов **юридического плана**, связанных с ИТ-деятельностью.

Главная метка - [юридические-аспекты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8e%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b). У неё более академическое название, да и описание получше:

> Используйте эту метку для вопросов о юридических аспектах создания, использования и/или распространения программных продуктов

Comment: Стоит подумать можно ли это как-то соотнести с [tag:авторские-права], [tag:права], [tag:лицензирование]

Comment: @αλεχολυτ [tag:юридичексие-аспекты] - более общая метка, чем предложенные вами.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а метку [tag:права] нужно вообще удалить (заменить либо на [tag:лицензирование], либо на [tag:права-доступа]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 24 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 22 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 21 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'закон': [закон] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 46
tag remapping of [юридические-аспекты] and [закон] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym закон -> юридические-аспекты was approved!
```